# color de relleno en un rectangulo itextsharp y vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Estoy elaborando un documento en PDF con itextsharp en Visual Basic 2010, y el cual lleva un rectangulo que me gustaría que tuviera color de relleno, he intentado con SetCMYKColorFill, pero no toma el color.

Quisiera saber como poder modificar el color de relleno del rectángulo.

Aquí está el código:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

Module pdfgenpda
Public pdfw As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter
Public rect As PdfContentByte
Public cb As PdfContentByte
Public fuente As iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont
Public nropda As String = "PDA " + genpda.Label17.Text

Sub genpdfpda()
    Dim ruta As String = "C:\Karuai\"
    Dim oDoc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 40, 40, 100, 10)
    Dim NombreArchivo As String = ruta + nropda + ".pdf"
    pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(oDoc, New FileStream(NombreArchivo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    Try
        oDoc.Open()
        cb = pdfw.DirectContent
        oDoc.NewPage()

        rect = pdfw.DirectContent
        rect.Rectangle(245, 600, 53.0F, -17.0F)
        rect.SetLineWidth(1)
        rect.SetCMYKColorFill(23, 30, 40, 20)
        rect.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK)

        rect.Stroke()

        rect = pdfw.DirectContent
        rect.SetLineWidth(1)
        rect.SetCMYKColorFillF(23, 30, 40, 20)
        rect.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK)
        rect.RoundRectangle(245, 500, 53.0F, -17.0F, 2)
        rect.Stroke()

        pdfw.Flush()
        'cerrar
        oDoc.Close()
        Process.Start(NombreArchivo)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

La modificacin seria como sigue:

```
rectangulo.SetColorFill(New BaseColor(147, 148, 148)) 'En color RGB. Solo busca el codigo de tu color.
```

Comment: Hola. Esto reemplazaría alguna línea en el código del OP? Se añade en algún lugar? Considera añadir algo de contexto a tu respuesta.